# JSP custom-tag - jsp:doBody makes all tags within lowercase and doesn't evaluate body

Tags: jsp

I have a custom-tag `e:MyTag`

```
...
<%@ tag body-content = "tagdependent" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="e" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
...
<jsp:doBody />
<e:MyMessageTag key="someKey" />
...
```

I use this as `<e:MyTag><e:MyOtherTag /></e:MyTag>`

My problem: JSP seems to translate tags to lower case - so I see in the Body `<e:myothertag />` instead of the replaced code that should have come from `<e:MyOtherTag />`.

Is there some attribute to set or something similar that keeps the tags case-sensitive? Or is the value of `body-content` wrong?

The `<e:MyMessageTag />` gets evaluated correctly - it's just tags within the `<jsp:doBody />` that loose their case.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Oracle's The Java EE 5 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnamg/index.html) explains the attributes:

> You must declare the body content of tags that do not accept a body as empty. For tags that have a body there are two options. Body content containing custom and standard tags and HTML text is specified as scriptless. All other types of body content (for example, SQL statements passed to the query tag) is specified as tagdependent. If no attribute is specified, the default is scriptless.

So you have to declare the attribute as `scriptless` or just delete the line as it's the default value.